# How to use hashsolo for demultiplexing hashtags?

Tags: rna-seq, python, hashing

I am trying to use hashsolo and I want to make sure that I have done things correctly.

I did the below:

```
#import files
A= sc.read_10x_h5('filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5', gex_only=False)
A.var_names_make_unique()
A.layers["counts"] = A.X.copy()
sc.pp.filter_genes(A, min_counts=1)

#hashsolo
hto=A[:,A.var_names.str.startswith('HTO')].copy()
hashsolo.hashsolo(hto)
hashsolo.plot_qc_checks_cell_hashing(cell_hashing_data) #nothing gets plotted
A.obs['most_likely_hypothesis'] = hto.obs['most_likely_hypothesis']
A.obs['Classification'] = hto.obs['Classification']
```

Then since I have two samples for which I did hashsolo (A and B) I concatenated the objects and continued with the scanpy analysis like shown below:

```
sc.pl.highest_expr_genes(A_B, n_top=20, )
sc.pp.filter_cells(A_B, min_genes=200)
sc.pp.filter_genes(A_B, min_cells=3)
print(A_B.n_obs, A_B.n_vars)
```

and I continued with the mitochondria QC and the rest of the analysis.

Is that correct?

I am wondering if I should have done it differently. Like shown below

```
A= sc.read_10x_h5('filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5', gex_only=False)
A.var_names_make_unique() Then the 
sc.pl.highest_expr_genes(A, n_top=20, )
sc.pp.filter_cells(A, min_genes=200)
sc.pp.filter_genes(A, min_cells=3)
print(A.n_obs, A.n_vars)
```

and following the QC (filtering and mitochondria) and make the hto list and use hashsolo and then concatenate the 2 samples (A and B).